# Grabbing rows by count and another critera MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an orders table, where there is date_paid, to save the date a order has been processed.
Also I have a user_id column for the buyer.

How can i grab All user_id's (unique), that have made an order before date 2013-04-01 00:00:00 but have not made any orders after until todays date.

What I would have done is:

1. Grab all orders, unique user id: `GROUP BY orders.user_id WHERE orders.date_paid < '2013-04-01 00:00:00'`
2. Foreach loop through them and check if they have any orders after that date `WHERE date_paid > '2013-04-01 00:00:00'`

Can this be done, all by query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using aggregating and a `having` clause:

```
select user_id
from orders o
group by user_id
having sum(case when date_paid < '2013-04-01' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when date_paid >= '2013-04-01' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The first condition in the `having` clause counts the number of orders before 2013-04-01.  It requires that there be at least one order.  The second counts the number of orders since then.  It requires that there be no orders.

Answer (score 1):

```
select o.user_id
from orders o
GROUP BY o.user_id 
having sum(o.date_paid < '2013-04-01') > 0
and sum(o.date_paid > '2013-04-01') = 0
```